# Why is the result of this division "inf"?

Tags: python-3.x, divide-by-zero

I have the following code to compute a desired quantity:

```
import numpy as np

N = 2
lamda = 2
mu = 1
a = 0.5
St_Sp = np.arange(- N, N + 1)
Card = St_Sp.shape[0]

#%% Define infintesimal generator
def In_Ge(x, y):
    if x == N or x == - N:
        re = 0
    elif x - y == - 1:
        re = lamda
    elif x - y == 1:
        re = mu
    elif x - y == 0:
        re = - (mu + lamda)
    else: re = 0
    return re

x = St_Sp[0]
y = In_Ge(x, x) / (In_Ge(x, x) + np.log(a))
b = - 1 / y

print(b)
```

The result is `inf`. I checked and see that the value of `y` is non-zero, so I could not understand why such phenomenon happens. Could you elaborate on this issue?

Comment: Your 'In_Ge(x,x)' retruns 0, thus y= 0 and 1/0 is pretty badly defined. Edit: You say it's not, but your x==--2  and functions first if is invoked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@pinegulf's comment solves my question:

> Your 'In_Ge(x,x)' retruns 0, thus y= 0 and 1/0 is pretty badly defined. Edit: You say it's not, but your x==--2 and functions first if is invoked.